# Why aren't there implicit conversions in F#?

Tags: f#

F# does not support implicit conversions.  I understand that this is a feature, but I don't understand why implicit conversions are forbidden even when no information would be lost.  For example:

```
sqrt 4      // Won't compile.
```

I don't see a problem implicitly converting the `int` 4 to a `float`, which is what `sqrt` requires.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because its type checker almost depends on classical strong type-reconstruction. You example requires the *coercion* of types which is possible through implicit casts or a weak type system, but these aren't allowed in this kind of type inference.

Since **F#** comes from OCaml it has a type reconstruction that tries to guarantee correctness of your program by being extremely pedantic: the algorithm tries to unify the whole types of your program to a good typing and this cannot be done if a weak type rule allows to consider an integer like a float.

Comment: Did you mean, "... to consider an integer like a float"?

Comment: yes, fixed that also if the point can be reversed for the opposite case (widening or restricting numeral type)

Comment: Would it be better to say that having a weaker type rule, would lead to a much larger search space that the compiler has to process to prove that the types are all “logically correct”.

Comment: @IanRingrose: it's not a matter of performance, it's a precise design choice

Comment: @Jack,  I rather expect that the larger search space would make it impossible to write a compiler that worked in a dependable and understandable way.    Therefore a very good precise design choice not to allow it.   (Until systems like TypeScript solve the problem from the opersite direction.)

Answer (score 7):

See also

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/overview-of-type-inference-in-f/

which describes how overloading interacts badly with type inference.  Implicit conversions cause many of the same problems as overloading, and also interact poorly with error diagnostics.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the above answers, type conversions between integer and float are [not actually free](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-floating-point-to-integer-conversions/) in computational terms; the compiler is *not* doing you a favour by "hiding" them from you if your goal is to write high-performance code. This is one of the things I like about OCaml and F#: even tho' they are very high level, you still need to be aware of exactly what computation you are doing.